# Reading equations & formula from Word (Docx) to html and save database using java

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, docx4j

I have a word/docx file which has equations as under images
[image]

I want read data of file word/docx and save to my database
and when need I can get data from database and show on my html page
I used apache Poi for read data form docx file but It can't take equations
Please help me!

Comment: SUGGESTIONS:
1) Try an alternate library, like [OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/java/ref/overview-summary.html), [docxj4](https://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) or [javadocx](http://www.javadocx.com/download), and/or 2) Unzip your .docx and analyze the XML that's causing problems.  For 2), be sure to post back what you've learned.

Comment: I tried idea of Axel Richter and i resolved my issue. Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Word` `*.docx` files are `ZIP` archives containing `XML` files which are [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML). The formulas contained in `Word` `*.docx` documents are [Office MathML (OMML)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML_file_formats#Office_MathML_.28OMML.29).

Unfortunately this `XML` format is not really well known outside `Microsoft Office`. So it is not directly usable in `HTML` for example. But fortunately it is `XML` and as such it is transformable using [Transforming XML Data with XSLT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html). So we can transform that `OMML` into [MathML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML) for example, which is usable in a wider area of use cases.

A transformation process via `XSLT` mainly bases on a `XSL` definition of the transformation. Unfortunately creating a such is also not really easy.  But fortunately `Microsoft` has done that already and if you have a current `Microsoft Office` installed, you can find this file `OMML2MML.XSL` in the `Microsoft Office` program directory in `%ProgramFiles%\`. If you don't find it, do a web research to get it.

So if we are knowing this all, we can getting the `OMML` from the `XWPFDocument`, transforming it into `MathML` and then saving that for later usage.

My example stores the found formulas as `MathML` in a `ArrayList` of strings. You should also be able storing this strings in your data base.

The example needs the full `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar` as mentioned in https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025. This is because it uses [CTOMath](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/officeDocument/x2006/math/CTOMath.java#CTOMath) which is not shipped with the smaller `poi-ooxml-schemas jar`.

Word document:

[image]

Java code:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTOMath;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTOMathPara;

import org.w3c.dom.Node;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import java.awt.Desktop;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/*
needs the full ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar as mentioned in https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025
*/

public class WordReadFormulas {

 static File stylesheet = new File("OMML2MML.XSL");
 static TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
 static StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet); 

 static String getMathML(CTOMath ctomath) throws Exception {
  Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(stylesource);

  Node node = ctomath.getDomNode();

  DOMSource source = new DOMSource(node);
  StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();
  StreamResult result = new StreamResult(stringwriter);
  transformer.setOutputProperty("omit-xml-declaration", "yes");
  transformer.transform(source, result);

  String mathML = stringwriter.toString();
  stringwriter.close();

  //The native OMML2MML.XSL transforms OMML into MathML as XML having special name spaces.
  //We don't need this since we want using the MathML in HTML, not in XML.
  //So ideally we should changing the OMML2MML.XSL to not do so.
  //But to take this example as simple as possible, we are using replace to get rid of the XML specialities.
  mathML = mathML.replaceAll("xmlns:m=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math\"", "");
  mathML = mathML.replaceAll("xmlns:mml", "xmlns");
  mathML = mathML.replaceAll("mml:", "");

  return mathML;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("Formula.docx"));

  //storing the found MathML in a AllayList of strings
  List<String> mathMLList = new ArrayList<String>();

  //getting the formulas out of all body elements
  for (IBodyElement ibodyelement : document.getBodyElements()) {
   if (ibodyelement.getElementType().equals(BodyElementType.PARAGRAPH)) {
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph)ibodyelement;
    for (CTOMath ctomath : paragraph.getCTP().getOMathList()) {
     mathMLList.add(getMathML(ctomath));
    }
    for (CTOMathPara ctomathpara : paragraph.getCTP().getOMathParaList()) {
     for (CTOMath ctomath : ctomathpara.getOMathList()) {
      mathMLList.add(getMathML(ctomath));
     }
    }
   } else if (ibodyelement.getElementType().equals(BodyElementType.TABLE)) {
    XWPFTable table = (XWPFTable)ibodyelement; 
    for (XWPFTableRow row : table.getRows()) {
     for (XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
      for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : cell.getParagraphs()) {
       for (CTOMath ctomath : paragraph.getCTP().getOMathList()) {
        mathMLList.add(getMathML(ctomath));
       }
       for (CTOMathPara ctomathpara : paragraph.getCTP().getOMathParaList()) {
        for (CTOMath ctomath : ctomathpara.getOMathList()) {
         mathMLList.add(getMathML(ctomath));
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }

  document.close();

  //creating a sample HTML file 
  String encoding = "UTF-8";
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("result.html");
  OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, encoding);
  writer.write("<!DOCTYPE html>\n");
  writer.write("<html lang=\"en\">");
  writer.write("<head>");
  writer.write("<meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>");

  //using MathJax for helping all browsers to interpret MathML
  writer.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\"");
  writer.write(" async src=\"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=MML_CHTML\"");
  writer.write(">");
  writer.write("</script>");

  writer.write("</head>");
  writer.write("<body>");
  writer.write("<p>Following formulas was found in Word document: </p>");

  int i = 1;
  for (String mathML : mathMLList) {
   writer.write("<p>Formula" + i++ + ":</p>");
   writer.write(mathML);
   writer.write("<p/>");
  }

  writer.write("</body>");
  writer.write("</html>");
  writer.close();

  Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new File("result.html").toURI());

 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Just tested this code using `apache poi 5.0.0` and it works. You need `poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar` for `apache poi 5.0.0`. Please read https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025 for what `ooxml` libraries are needed for what `apache poi` version.

Comment: Hi @Axel Richter
Now i want read all content from my docx. Such as the photo above I need to get the whole paragraph , Example: enter image description here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFifn.png
What should I do.Can you guide me?

Comment: @NHT: Yes, do that. Nobody stops you ;-). In serious: This is not how this Q/A site works. Do not ask a question, get an answer to it and then add additional requirements. This question has been answered already. If you have a new question, ask a new question. But in this new question show your own effort by showing what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @NHT: Yes it will be "really a bit difficult". But as a hint: The [CTP](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTP.java) extends `org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject`. So you could using a [XmlCursor](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/2.4.0/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlCursor.java) to go through the paragraph from top to down having access to all of its inner elements including the text runs and the `oMath`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Axel Richter answer, I found it really hard to find the required set of dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
```

And with Office 2019 I guess they don't provide `OMML2MML.XSL` so here's the link for it https://github.com/Versal/word2markdown/blob/master/libs/omml2mml.xsl