# Reading equations & formula from Word (Docx) to html

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, docx4j

I have a word/docx file which has equations as under formulas  ， 
but my display is not normal, as follows:

(2×-1+3i2)3[(1+i)2]3

In the process of implementation, reference is [Reading equations & formula from Word (Docx) to html and save database using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44748712/reading-equations-formula-from-word-docx-to-html-and-save-database-using-jav)

Comment: Do you have a question for us?

Comment: Do describing what you have tried. What Word docx file do you have with what kind of formulas in it? What exact code have you used? What code part has failed and how?

Comment: Just tested. My answer in the linked question works using `apache poi 3.17`. It also works using `apache poi 4.0.1` but of course there the `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` is needed instead of `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar`.