# Equations in mathml format from Word (*.docx) with their text context using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

We are trying to build to java code to read the word document (docx file) using apache POI. I have taken hint from this solution [Reading equations from Word (*.docx) to HTML together with their text context using apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59414033/reading-equations-from-word-docx-to-html-together-with-their-text-context-us). I have imported the required dependencies.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have imported the exact CTP and CTOMath functions.

```
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTOMath;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTOMathPara;
```

I have changed the xsl file to MML2OMML.XSL which i got from Microsoft Office folder in Windows. Earlier i used the described xsl file (OMML2MML.XSL) which gave me more errors.

The problem is i am not getting desired mathml output.

My input was word doc like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxIvO.png)

My output was

- mathml for formula 1:
- mathml for formula 2:
- Text: Hi this is Nikhil

Could somebody please help me here? Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just tested my code in linked answer using `apache poi 5.0.0` and it works. You need `OMML2MML.XSL` as `MML2OMML.XSL` converts the other way around. And you need `poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar` for `apache poi 5.0.0`.

Comment: @Axel Richter I included all the same requirements like poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar for apache poi 5.0.0. But i have to use TransformerFactory tFactory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();  as XSL transformer was not supporting the XSLT script version that had been used, so I switched to SAXON. Now i am getting mathMLList:[x+an=k=0nnkxkan-k, a2+b2=c2]. It's latex format not mathml. Could you kindly help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, sorry, then I cannot help. My answer is tested and works using `javax.xml.transform`. This is the default Java transformer API. Why not using this? But your result looks as if the browser simply is not able showing `MathML` properly. Have a look into the source of the `result.html`. There you will find properly coded `MathML`, I bet.

Comment: I am sorry. It does not work with javax.xml.transform that why i have to switch to saxon. I looked into the source. I found this. 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=MML_CHTML"></script></head><body><p>x+an=k=0nnkxkan-k</p><p></p><p></p><p>a2+b2=c2</p><p></p><p></p><p>Hi this is nikhil</p></body></html> Equations looks like general text.