# Converting XWPFDocument to PDF loses maths formulas

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I am attempting to convert a XWPFDocument to PDF format and everything except the maths formulas are being exported. I believe this is to do with the convert method in opensagres's PdfConverter class.

When decompiling and attempting to search for the root of the problem, it led me to the `visitBodyElements` method in the `XWPFDocumentVisitor` class.

```
protected void visitBodyElements(List<IBodyElement> bodyElements, T container) throws Exception {
    if (!this.masterPageManager.isInitialized()) {
        this.masterPageManager.initialize();
    }

    String previousParagraphStyleName = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < bodyElements.size(); ++i) {
        IBodyElement bodyElement = (IBodyElement)bodyElements.get(i);

        switch(bodyElement.getElementType()) {
            case PARAGRAPH:
                XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph)bodyElement;
                String paragraphStyleName = paragraph.getStyleID();
                boolean var10000;
                if (paragraphStyleName != null && paragraphStyleName.equals(previousParagraphStyleName)) {
                    var10000 = true;
                } else {
                    var10000 = false;
                }

                this.visitParagraph(paragraph, i, container);
                break;

            case TABLE:
                previousParagraphStyleName = null;
                this.visitTable((XWPFTable)bodyElement, i, container);
                break;

            case CONTENTCONTROL:
                this.visitSDT((XWPFSDT)bodyElement, i, container);
        }
    }

}
```

This method does not contain a case where the bodyElement is a formula and I believe this is why it is not being converted to PDF. However, it that the case? How are Maths formulas being stored in the `XWPFDocument` class?

Comment: At first `XWPFDocumentVisitor` is not a `apache poi`class but a [XDocReport](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/blob/master/thirdparties-extension/fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core/src/main/java/fr/opensagres/poi/xwpf/converter/core/XWPFDocumentVisitor.java) class. `XDocReport` uses `apache poi` but both projects are not related to each other. And no, it does not considering [Office MathML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML_file_formats#Office_MathML_.28OMML.29) equations up to now. So pull an issue or a request [there](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport).

Comment: I have provided code to convert that not really well known `Office MathML` to the better known [MathML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44748712/reading-equations-formula-from-word-docx-to-html-and-save-database-using-jav/44809755#44809755 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59414033/reading-equations-from-word-docx-to-html-together-with-their-text-context-us/59502090#59502090. But converting that into PDF will be a much more tedious task then.

Comment: Is "`` enter code here`` " [intentional](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70742097/edit)? (Last line in the posted code.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Does anyone have an idea on how we could go about getting these maths formulas into pdf as well as powerpoint.